# How to get facebook user id by user url?

Tags: facebook

Looking to get user profile image url by enter user url, but I see that api not allowed get it by user url but with user id.

My question is - how can I get the username ID by giving the user url?
like here - https://lookup-id.com/

Thanks :)

Comment: You can’t, not in any allowed way. Those lookup services directly scrape the Facebook profile page, which is not allowed. In short: Your app should not be dealing with users that did not explicitly login to it, or that it did not get the id for via another API request (such as the current user’s friends, that also use the app) in the first place.

Comment: Each facebook application would have unique user id. And you can use this user id to 'https://graph.facebook.com/{user-id}/picture?type=square'